# StretchDIBits issue

Tags: delphi, blend, stretchdibits

I want to blit 32bit image (PNG with alpha channel) over 32bit Bitmap (or Bitmap32).

I don't know how to tell function to blend image instead of bliting it. Like using AlphaBlend instead of BitBlt, I need to make this function to blend image instead of simple blit.

This is my example:

ABitmap is type of TBitmap32 (GR32), but the same result is with regular TBitmap with 32bit palette.

```
    ABitmap.SetSize(GetWidth, GetHeight);
    SetStretchBltMode(ABitmap.Handle, COLORONCOLOR);//HALFTONE);
    ABitmap.Clear($FFFFFFFF);  { Here I try to erase background with white color, so that new image is blit over white surface }
    StretchDIBits(
      ABitmap.Handle,
      0, 0,
      GetWidth, GetHeight,
      0, 0,
      GetWidth, GetHeight,
      FreeImage_GetBits(Dib),
      FreeImage_GetInfo(Dib)^,
      DIB_RGB_COLORS,
      SRCCOPY);    // --- SRCAND etc. produce not good results
```

FreeImage_GetBits and FreeImage_GetInfo are FreeImage library functions that point to the start of bit array and point to the structure.

What ever I do StretchDBit doesn't allow blending.

Answer (score 2):

`StretchDIBits()` does not have any concept of alpha-blending.  You will have to blit your PNG to a temporary 32-bit bitmap first, making sure to set up its alpha channel as needed, and then `AlphaBlend()` the temporary bitmap onto your destination bitmap.  Or, you could just `AlphaBlend()` the PNG directly to the destination bitmap if the PNG is laid out in memory using a 32-bit bitmap already.

Comment: The whole concept of alpha blending is foreign to most GDI functions. It was bolted on very late in the game.

Comment: True. Even later in the game, the VCL's `TCanvas.Draw()` method just in the last year or two finally received support for alpha-blending via `AlphaBlend()` when drawing bitmaps.

Comment: AlphaBlend function expect Canvas.Handle (HDC) instead of memory array. It's DDB and not DIB (Device Independed Bitmap) function. I'm looking some DIB blend function.

Comment: `AlphaBlend()` works with DIBs. [Microsoft's own example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183353.aspx) shows a DIB being used.